# DRF Custom Update password got KeyError: 'request'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

When I want to update password received error,

```
 user = self.context['request'].user
KeyError: 'request'
```

Can someone help me with it?

**serializer:**
Custom serializer

```
class UserPasswordChangeSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    old_password = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    password = serializers.CharField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('old_password', 'password')

    def validate_old_password(self, data):
        user = self.context['request'].user
        if not user.check_password(data):
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                {'old_password': 'Wrong password.'}
            )
        return data

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        return super().update(instance)
```

**My action view**
My action view

```
@action(methods=['patch'], detail=True)
    def change_password(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user = self.get_object()
        user.serializer = UserPasswordChangeSerializer(data=request.data)
        user.serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user.serializer.save()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass `request` as context variable to the serializer

```
@action(methods=['patch'], detail=True)
def change_password(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    user = self.get_object()
    user.serializer = UserPasswordChangeSerializer(data=request.data,
                                                   context={'request': request})
    user.serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    user.serializer.save()
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

**Reference:** [Including extra context in Serializer](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context)

Comment: thx it helps , now i got this error `create() must be implemented.` do you know what's the problem?

Comment: Probably you should a new question